# Regular expression validator that checks if user entered a value rounded to nearest 100

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am working in vb.net. I want to create a validator that checks if the user has entered a value that is in hundreds only.  i.e. 100,200,300,400,500...1100,1200,1300,1400...100000,100100 and so on.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a regex? This would achieve the same result and perform better.

```
If inputString.EndsWith("00") And Integer.TryParse(inputString, 0) Then
   'Is a number in the hundreds...
End If
```

Here's a live fiddle:
http://dotnetfiddle.net/Z0iwt6

Comment: Great! Thanks! I had not thought of that. Works great!

Comment: No probs, I added a fiddle so you can test with a few values.

Comment: @user1578047 That code will break if 1.00 is entered.  You should use a modulus operation.

Comment: 1.00 will fail the `Integer.TryParse`. Check for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*00$
```

This will match a single decimal digit from 1 to 9, followed by zero or more of any decimal digits, followed by two `0`'s. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors ensure that no other characters will be allowed in the input. For example:

```
Dim match = Regex.Match("1200", "^[1-9][0-9]*00$")
Console.WriteLine(match.Success) // True
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    Dim result As Double = 0
    If Double.TryParse(Output(0), result) AndAlso Math.IEEERemainder(result, 100) = 0 Then
        'process input here
    End If
```